# How I can block the internal harddisk, on debian?

Tags: debian, live, blocking, internal, usb-drive

How I can block the internal harddisk when I start Debian with a USB stick?

If I boot with my created ISO, I have the Debian system, but I can access my normal Win7 partition.

I would like to deny access to my Win7 harddisk when booting with the USB live Debian stick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a secure solution, you should encrypt your Windows7 partition with Truecrypt or Bitlocker, so nobody can access it, neither with your Debian live system, nor with any other USB stick or live CD.

Comment: i will make a debian live system for learner so that he can make exams on his own laptop, but without the data on his internal harddisk.